# Find all the functions $f : \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ such that $f(x+f(f(y)))=y+f(f(x))$ for all integers $(x,y)$

Tags: proof-verification, functional-equations

> Find all the functions $f : \Bbb Z \rightarrow \Bbb Z$ with the property that  for all integers $(x,y)$ the equation holds:
>   $$f(x+f(f(y)))=y+f(f(x))$$

**My solution:** $f(x+f(f(y)))=y+f(f(x))$ means that also is possible

$$f(y+f(f(x)))=x+f(f(y))$$

Putting this in the first equation we get:

$$f[f(y+f(f(x)))]=y+f(f(x))$$

This is equal to $f(f(K))=K$ with $K=y + f(f(x))$, in other words, any number.

Replacing: $f(f(x))=x$ and $f(f(y))=y$ in $f(x+f(f(y)))=y+f(f(x))$:

$$f(x+y)=y+x$$

That's equal to $f(x)=x$.

It's this correct or not?, If it's wrong, any hints?.

Comment: $K$ doesn't have to be 'every' number: $f$ is not necessarily surjective

Comment: @Mastrem That doesn't matter, you can just change the $y$.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'd still put something like $x=0$, giving $f(f(f(y)))=y+f(f(0))$ where the right side is bijective, so the left side as well, implying $f$ is bijective

Comment: Absolutely correct as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good.  To be a bit more precise, you could explain that $y+f(f(x))$ can be any integer $n$ by choosing $x$ arbitrarily and then setting $y=n-f(f(x))$, and similarly for $x+y$ at the end of your argument.